# WEBPACK How can I add a <script> which src has a completely http path into a html

Tags: webpack

Currently, I need add `<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>` into my html via webpack, that is a third party library has a completely path.  Are there any plugins can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack doesn't actually load from an HTML file because it is strictly a Javascript loader.

Inside of your index.js, import scripts and styles

`import jsfile from '.src/js/anotherJsFile';
import style from '../css/styles.css';`

That will tell webpack to load those files into the entry point.
For html, use html-webpack-plugin like so

```
plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin
      ({
        title:'My webpage!',
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'src/public/index.html'
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin
      ({
        title:'About me!',
        filename: 'about.html',
        template: 'src/public/about.html'
      })
    ]
```

this will use your original html as templates to fill in a newly created html file inside of the dist folder for you.

edit

Also to use es6 you will need to load with babel

```
rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                presets: ["babel-preset-env"]
              }
            }
        }
```

and this should be what your package.json or whatever looks like

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack-css-loaders": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
```